# What can I do instead execute stored procedure in sql server function

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In a select statement I am calling a function which I should show result of it in the result table of select statement. In this function, I need to recreate (it is just checking actually if it is necessary to be recreated or not then it will recreate if necessary) a table which the function uses and I know I can not do that in a function so I created a stored procedure to recreate the table.

I can not exec stored procedure before the select statement because I need to do that in every row. Because the content of the table may need to be changed according to parameters of it every time.

But I know that I also can not exec a stored procedure within a function because of this error `Only functions and some extended stored procedures can be executed from within a function.` So in final situation, I need to exec stored procedure in a function in order to recreate the table or I need to create a non-temporary table in a function. I could not find any solution for this. Is there any solution to do that in a different way?

---

I am trying to explain what am I trying to do in details. The table that I mentioned above, stores a list of start times and end times of some workers. In the function I am using this time informations and doing something with it.

But In my select statement I am sending a time parameter to the funciton and this time can be old,  for example a month ago. And start and end hours of workers can be different at a month ago. So in this situation according to time parameter of the function I may need to recreate the table. But I can not do that in a function so I did it in a stored procedure but I can not exec this stored procedure in a function as well. And I also can not create a table in the function.

Comment: My guess is this is an xy question. Having to recreate a table for **every** row in a dataset sounds like an awful idea. Post the SQL and explain what it does, I imagine there is a far better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Larnu It will not be recreated actually, It just will check if it is necessary or not according to content of the parameters. I guess it will be recreated one times in a month maybe.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. In your question you state *" created a stored procedure to recreate the table"* and *" can not exec stored procedure before the select statement because I need to do that in every row. "*. If you need to `EXEC` it at every row, then you're saying that you want to recreate the table at every row. If this isn't the case, then what you're saying above isn't correct. This is why we need to see your SQL, and understand what you're true goal is.

Comment: @Larnu Code is really huge so I will try to explain what I am doing in the code, I am updating the question now.

Comment: @Larnu I updated it

Comment: That doesn't help us, I'm afraid. For example *"doing something with it"* it probably the least descriptive phrase you could have chosen. This question needs a lot of work for others to be able to help you. Sample data, expected result and (like i said before ) SQL is going be needed, otherwise we can't help you. The volunteers on SO can't access your server, and they can't read your mind, so they have no way to help you without a lot of guess work; and then they could just end up wasting their time (which, isn't something any of us want to do).

Comment: @Larnu I believe I gave a lot more than information that needed to solve this problem. Thanks for your time, maybe some others can say something.

Comment: With the obvious exception of `SELECT .. INTO`, you can't make a `SELECT` create a table. You could put the `SELECT` inside a stored procedure as well, which is then free to call the other stored procedure according to the results. Otherwise, this sounds like a job for a [scheduled job](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job) and/or a [startup procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql).

Comment: A function can return a table (variable). Do maybe, instead of changing a(n "external") table (which seems like a bad idea anyway) let the function return a table reflecting the changes. But I'm with Larnu. There is not enough information in the question to give more than a very vague advise and having the feeling we talk XY here.